# Having issues with blurring fuctio

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing the CS50 - I dont want the answers just an idea of where i am going wrong.

I have managed to sort the edge and corners but some reason the normal 3x3 pixels are getting the wrong values.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
  // Create a copy of the image
  RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

  // Iterate over each pixel in the image
  for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      // Copy the current pixel to the copy
      copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
    }
  }

  // Iterate over each pixel in the image again
  for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      // Initialize the total values
      int totalRed = 0;
      int totalBlue = 0;
      int totalGreen = 0;
      int squares = 0;

      // Iterate over the 3x3 neighborhood of the current pixel
      for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
          // If the pixel is within the image, add its value to the averages
          if (h + i >= 0 && h + i < height && w + j >= 0 && w + j < width) {
            totalRed += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtRed;
            totalBlue += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtBlue;
            totalGreen += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtGreen;
            squares++;
          }
        }
      }

      // If there are any pixels in the neighborhood, set the current pixel to the average
      if (squares > 0) {
        image[h][w].rgbtRed = round(totalRed / squares);
        image[h][w].rgbtBlue = round(totalBlue / squares);
        image[h][w].rgbtGreen = round(totalGreen / squares);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried adding all the 3x3 then divide by the number of pixels which i have checked is 9 so it is doing the full 3x3 fine. Im just confused because it does the corners and edges fine.

Comment: Just as a side note: Don't even iterate over j if i is already out of range...

Comment: Dividing the integer totals by the number of squares is _Integer division_... Try converting/casting at least one of the variables to `double` before the division happens.

Comment: Squares cannot get 0, even on a single pixel image there's the pixel itself you'd be counting, and on an empty image (no pixels at all) you wouldn't even iterate.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I wouldn't cast to double, but (as values are unsigned anyway) simply add half of `squares` before rounding, that's more efficient.

Comment: Yet another side note: Correct type for array lengths is `size_t` (from `stddef.h`), albeit `int` not sufficing might be unrealistic. At least you should prefer `unsigned int` as negative sizes are meaningless anyway (-> self-documenting code).

Comment: @Aconcagua Fine, but with a comment explaining the reason, I hope.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Depends on what *'wrong value'* actually means – if *'too little by one sometimes'* then definitely ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the tips that make sense, didn't even know what size_t was. Just did some research into it and that makes sense.

Comment: `memcpy(copy, image, sizeof(copy))` would be a bit more elegant than the double loop, wouldn't it? Likely a bit more efficient (highly optimised), too.

Comment: `for (int i = h - 1;  i <= h + 1;  i++)` and the same for the next line with `j` and `w` makes the clipping condition a little easier to read IMO.

Comment: Err.. Partially erroneous comment of mine previously – simply add half of `squares` *before division* (and drop the call to `round` entirely, that's obsolete then; i.e. `targetValue = (sourceValue + squares / 2) / squares;` – the pure integer way of rounding, though not correct for negative values, these need a little extra tweak ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not using a floating point value in the division. Thanks to @Fe203 for pointing this out.

Comment: Floating point is rather expensive, though – and is not suitable for integer types as large as the floating point type you use (losing precision!). Much cheaper is simply adding half of `squares` before division (unless you need to fear overflow) – at least for positive values, which I assume here, though (RGB values in range of [0; 255], at most nine of -> no overflow risk here either).